# Why regex doesn't work? Swift

Tags: regex, url, swift, nsregularexpression

I have this regex expression that works on http://www.regexr.com but not in iOS. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "v=(.+?)(?=\\s|&)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
```

Original regex: **v=(.+?)(?=\s|&)**

Regex is applied over this test URLs (separated):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjifp5oi6dE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdigMMGadDM&feature=relmfu
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdigMMGadDM&feature=relmfu&asdsadsa
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdigMMGadDM&feature=relmfu&asdsadsa&asdfasdasdasQ%4&asdsadsad
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=relmfu&asdsadsa&asdfasdasdasQ%4&asdsadsad&v=gdigMMGadDM
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the code:

```
// Get video ID
var error: NSError?
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "v=(.+?)(?=\\s|&)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
println(originalURL)
println(regex)
let match: NSTextCheckingResult? = regex.firstMatchInString(originalURL, options: NSMatchingOptions(0), range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(originalURL)))
println(match)
let videoID = (originalURL as NSString).substringWithRange(match!.range).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("v=", withString: "")
println(videoID)
```

"match" is nil!

**EDIT 2:**

Expected results: [regexr.com/39loc](http://www.regexr.com/39loc)

Comment: What does ***not work*** mean?

Comment: simply, no matches found! I tried with all options of NSRegularExpressionOptions but nothing

Comment: I think he means what pattern are you attempting to extract from each of these URLs.

Comment: @PiJoules No, I don't really care about the pattern because that doesn't matter. To clarify, how is the regex being used and what is the result?

Comment: Example of expected result: http://regexr.com/39loc

Comment: you will have to show more code, please.

Comment: I added the code at original question. Thanks!

Comment: You may need to double-backslash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern does not find "v=..." at *the end* of the string, because `(?=\\s|&)` expects
a following white space or "&" character. With `"v=(.+?)(?=$|&)"` you should get the expected result.

Comment: Martin, the result is not as expected: http://regexr.com/39lof Not all cases are met

Comment: @mhergon: It seems that http://regexr.com treats `\s` and `$` differently from Swift with `NSRegularExpression`. I did test this with Swift code where it produced the expected result.

Comment: Ooh, that's right! Sorry! I tried with "v=(.+?)(?=$|&|\\s)" and works, but your solution "v=(.+?)(?=$|&)" also works. Thanks!